# When accessing HBase from Java the first connection is very slow. Is it normal?

Tags: java, hbase, apache-zookeeper

We have a java servlet that connects to a couple of HBase tables on top of Hadoop via `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.HTable`.

Invariably the first HTable instantiation will be very slow (~2800ms) while subsequent call will be fast (~60ms).

Reading the HTable class source it indicates that zookeeper connections are shared across HTable instances, hence this could correspond to some zookeeper initialization delay but still I am wondering if others see a similar delay and if there is some configuration option that could speed things up?

Comment: Your comment is helpful. We don't use HTablePool, we were using a shared HTable instance. I now see that using an HTable instance is not recommended in a multithreaded environment, which is our case. I am going to investigate HTablePool a bit more and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigation it seems that yes it is normal that the first `HTable` initialization takes several seconds. Several sources recommend using `HTablePool` to share the HTable interfaces accross threads and thus avoid to incur the initialization delay more than once. The `HTable` object itself should not be shared because it is not threadsafe.